# iPhone: Ovi maps

Tags: iphone, dictionary, nokia

I want to use Ovi map in my iPhone application. I searched for Ovi map on google  but presently it is not open.Basically I want to know following things

1. OVi map service is from Nokia. So can i use Ovi Map in my iPhone application.
2. If answer of 1 point is Yes, then where I found support info(code sample/classes/framework) for iPhone.

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Ovi Maps developer beta is currently closed, but you can register to be notified when it goes public here: http://www.forum.nokia.com/Ovi/Develop_with_Ovi.xhtml

Comment: I know it is closed. I just want to ask whether it is possible to use their API in iPhone. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the HERE maps service (formerly Ovi Maps) on iOS, a native iOS SDK is not currently available. To use HERE maps, your best bet (at the moment) would be to use the [Mobile HTML5 Framework](http://developer.here.net/mobile_html5) which can be used for cross-platform mobile HTML5 development

According to the [support matrix](http://developer.here.net/docs/mobile_js/topics/overview.html#platform-support) the following OSes are supported:

- **iOS 4.3+**
- Android 2.2+
- Meego
- Blackberry Touch devices OS6, OS7 (experimental)
- Windows Phone 8.0 (experimental)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use their SDK on the Iphone. They use the Ovi Maps service to promote their mobile phones just like google offers free navigation to android devices.
Therefore I think that they won't open up their API for not Nokia developers in the near future.